# Configuration of custom Wordpress-Docker build process

Tags: wordpress, docker

So, what I often find is that out Wordpress builds start from almost the same base - with the same plugins etc (e.g., WooCommerce when we're building a shop etc). What we're looking at is using Docker for local development and deploying to production.

However, the issue we're having is building from our base and then being able to locate the mapped development directory on our local machines with the added plugin directories. Essentially, we will maintain the plugins we want and ensure that they are good with the latest stable release of Wordpress and we will pull down the latest Wordpress docker image so we don't have to maintain that side of things too closely...

**Dockerfile**:

```
FROM wordpress:php7.1-apache
COPY wordpress-docker-build/wordpress-plugins /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins
```

**docker-compose.yml** (something like):

```
services:
  wp:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: qwerty
    volumes:
      - /Users/username/Developer/repos/my-wordpress-site:/var/www/html
  mysql:
    image: "mysql:5.7"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: qwerty
```

Essentially, what we find is when we remove `volumes` from `docker-compose.yml` - we have exactly the plugins we want. When we add in the volume mapping to the wordpress service, only the base wordpress image is installed and mapped across...no plugins.

We've tried all manor of tutorials, documentations, trial and error etc but a lot of head-scratching has ensued...

Answer (score 0):

Volumes don't work like that. When you mount something into the container at `/var/www/html`, it replaces that directory and everything in it.

If you don't have `/Users/username/Developer/repos/my-wordpress-site/wp-content/plugins` being mapped from your host, it won't exist in the container after the mount. The mount isn't additive, it totally replaces what existed in the container with what you have on the host.

> However, the issue we're having is building from our base and then being able to locate the mapped development directory on our local machines with the added plugin directories.

Bind mounted volumes are a one-way street in this regard, from the host to the container, with the implications discussed above. You can't use volumes to retrieve files from a container and edit them on the host. The closest thing to that is the `docker cp` command, but that's not helpful in this case.

The easiest way to accomplish what you want is using a bind mount to put the plugins from your host to the running container, either by placing them in `/Users/username/Developer/repos/my-wordpress-site/wp-content/plugins` on the host, or adding a second bind mount that only targets the plugins directory (`/some/other/dir:/var/www/html/wp-content/plugins`) if that's more convenient.

Also, if the COPY is only in your Dockerfile to support each developer's own effort developing plugins, and not to build an image to pass around or deploy to some other environment, you can probably just remove the line. It's overridden by the bind mount now and would be in the future if you're intention is being able to edit the plugins in a live container using a bind mount.

edit: misunderstood OP's dilemma

Comment: Hi there - thank you for taking the time to help on this. However, I've run into the following issue: `: Named volume "wordpress-repos/my-site/wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content:rw" is used in service "wordpress" but no declaration was found in the volumes section.`

Comment: Ok, so what is this doing exactly? Why are we declaring plugins like this?

Comment: When you use a bind mount and map it into the container at `/var/www/html`, it doesn't work like you're copying+overwriting files into `/var/www/html`. It more like you are deleting the `/var/www/html` directory and everything in it, *then* copying files into it. `wp-content/` doesn't survive this, so thus your `plugins/` dir doesn't either, and those plugins are missing when you run the container. That's also why it works when you removed the volume originally. An effect of using a named volume, that directory (`plugins/`) get's protected in the container, so the bind mount doesn't delete it.

Comment: Sidenote: I can't find anywhere this behavior is documented. If you deal with volumes all day and have a good understanding of what they work, it kind of makes logical sense that it would happen when using them together. I'm sure I read it somewhere, but I can't find it right now.

Comment: Doesn't make sense on first inspection to have a configuration like this tbh. When the container is thrown up you should be able to map it back to a directory/location on your local machine to be able to make changes.

Comment: This hasn't helped at all - I want to bind a standard set of plugins we will keep elsewhere, then make sure that we can still access the volume for changes on our local machine. I think you have misunderstood the question.

Comment: I don't have enaugh reputation to comment above post, which @**Wind Up Lord Vexxos** is the author... The problem that you can encounter which says: `ERROR: Named volume "wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content:rw" is used in service "wordpress" but no declaration was found in the volumes section.` exists because you provided relative path badly formatted. Don't forget about `./` before relative path to local directory. In my case mounting docker's `wp-content` directory to local `wp-content` looks like: volumes: - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content